# Subtracting consecutive points on a row in igor

Tags: igor

I have thousands of data points and I want to subtract two consecutive points and add the value to a new column. I tried to idex the row but it seems like igor doesn't work same way as python. Is there a cmd line that will calculate the change of consecutive data points? Say for instance I have a data

```
wave0= 1 3 8 9 12 18
```

And I want

```
wave1= 2 5 1 3 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `p, q, r, s` wave indexing in Igor Pro for that.

So something like

```
Make/O wave0 = {1, 3, 8, 9, 12, 18}
Make/O/N=5 wave1
wave1[] = wave0[p + 1] - wave0[p]
```

should do the trick.